# Como corrigir esse erro do NODEMON?

Tags: react, nodemon

Queria pedir ajuda para resolver esse problema. Estou fazendo um curso de React Native online mas o instrutor não responde minhas dúvidas. Não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema. Segue o erro:

```
    [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
C:\Users\Administrador\APP-REACT\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\Administrador\APP-REACT\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\Administrador\APP-REACT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrador\APP-REACT\src\routes\TaskRoutes.js:6:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrador\APP-REACT\src\index.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Se precisar de mais detalhes é so dizer. Vou passar imagens do codigo. Obrigado.

[imagens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGQol.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar o código?

Comment: Olá, amigo. Qual o codigo preciso postar? Sou iniciante em React.

Comment: TaskRoutes.js e o controller associado a ele, se tiver.

Comment: Amigo, coloquei umas imagens. Não sei qual a função de callback está se referindo.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta, poderia verificar se soluciona o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro não está relacionado com o nodemon.

O nodemon não conseguiu carregar os módulos, devido a falha na compilação.

Tem um erro no arquivo TaskValidation linha 7.

Faltou adicionar a aspas duplas (") na sua string.

onde existe:

```
return res.status(400).json({error: é obriga});
```

deveria ser:

```
return res.status(400).json({error: "macaddress é obrigatório"});
```

Comment: Amigo, o eterno erro de principiante =D. Deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado.